# Regex to match lines not containing multiple whole words in any order

Tags: java, regex, xcode, logic

i need to exclude two strings on same line using AND. but i am not able to apply proper Regex. please help.

here below example, I want to exclude 'badword' and 'test' both.
Test String:

```
ghjghj badword test ghjghj
one two
abadwords
three
```

and the regex used is `^((?!badword).*.((?!test).))*$`

Comment: Use two lookaheads anchored at the start: `^(?!.*badword)(?!.*test).*$`. However, this can easily be replaced with a non-regex approach with `contains` or `indexOf` methods.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: i am getting two match for it. string `abadwords` is also exclude, which in my case it is required.

Comment: Then use word boundaries: `^(?!.*\bbadword\b)(?!.*\btest\b).*$`

Comment: Thanks it Worked !!!

Comment: @Prayag See my full answer with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

To match lines that do not contain several whole words you may use either an alternation inside one [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) anchored at the start or use several negative lookaheads each containing a single whole word matching pattern:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:badword|test)\b).*$
```

Or

```
^(?!.*\bbadword\b)(?!.*\btest\b).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yGFiUG/1). You might need to use a multiline modifier to make `^` and `$` match start/end of *lines*.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string/line
- `(?!.*\b(?:badword|test)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 0+ chars other than line break chars followed with a word boundary, `badword` or `test` substrings and then a word boundary
- `.*` - then having any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string/line.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
^(?!.*\bbadword\b)(?!.*\btest\b).*$
```